# Will a browser exploit also work after I have downloaded the website?

Tags: web-browser, exploit

When I visit a website which exploits a vulnerability in my browser and I save this website to my computer and open later the offline version can my browser be hacked again?

Comment: This depends on the details of the exploit and how you've downloaded the site. One could create on which still works and one could create one which does not.

Comment: I would download the website through the browser. On what does it depend if the exploit would still work or not?

Comment: There are various kinds of exploits, i.e. things which use security problems in the script engine or some plugin to execute code on your local system or things that use your system as a trampoline to attack other systems (like your router) or services on your local system. Explaining every possible attack and their preconditions and if they would run if the site is saved locally with a specific browser would be too broad (and I also know a subset), i.e. either accept "it depends" as answer or focus your question on a specific attack you had in mind.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, but not always.**

It depends on how the exploit works. Many exploits contain a second stage payload which the first stage (contained on the website) downloads and then executes. This is done for multiple reasons. For example, the first stage may test to see which second stage is appropriate for that individual browser version, operating system, etc. It may also serve to make it possible to easily update the second stage payload without needing to modify the first stage. Of course, it's also entirely possible for the entire exploit to be contained on the malicious webpage, making it dangerous to open it later.